# Parse multiple text files line by line but only the lines before a specific match

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm working on a large number of log files and I would like to parse all the lines before a specific match in each file.

Files look like this :

```
04/14/2022 02:07:19 SLK 1234 12345 86177500 ERROR - UPDSERVS: SERVICE :SOFTWARESERVICE - IS NOT INSTALLED
04/14/2022 02:07:58 SLK 1234 12345 86216625 ERROR - Bin File Creation and Dump Raw Output Disabled
04/14/2022 02:08:01 SLK 1234 4321 86219734 BADERROR(3328:1416) Default PROCESS TIMING THRESHOLD 10
04/14/2022 02:08:08 SLK 1234 4321 86226078 ETHERNET(4264:5628) USER 1 Cluster 1 ID 00EQ3G038651
04/14/2022 02:08:08 SLK 1234 4321 86226078 ETHERNET(4264:5628) USER 2 CLuster 2 ID 00EQ3G026434
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000664 Error 2022-04-13T02:09:07+02:00 LegacyErrorLog SYSERR(4320:4404) ERRORLOG.CPP(606) sscmd(5812:1) KEYINPUT.CPP(209) Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000649 Error 2022-04-13T02:09:07+02:00 LegacyErrorLog SYSERR(4320:4404) ERRORLOG.CPP(606) Closed the current active Error Log due to: Manual rollover.
```

And I want all the n lines (from all the files) before the pattern "Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER" excluding that line, then parse the data in an Excel spreadsheet like this :

```
Client ID ||     Date     ||   Time    || Error code|| Detail
SLK-1234      04/14/2022     02:07:19     12345        86177500 ERROR - UPDSERVS: SERVICE :SOFTWARESERVICE - IS NOT INSTALLED
SLK-1234      04/14/2022     02:07:19     12345        86216625 ERROR - Bin File Creation and Dump Raw Output Disabled
SLK-1234      04/14/2022     02:07:19      4321        86219734 BADERROR(3328:1416) Default PROCESS TIMING THRESHOLD 10
```

I "think" I got the first part correct with this code :

```
$move = "X:\New\test\Output"
$root = "X:\New\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter *.*

$Results = foreach( $File in $Files ){
$location = $root+"\"+$file

    $s = Select-String -Path "$location" -Pattern "Command: ROLLOVER ERRORLOG" -Context ?,0 |
        Foreach-Object { $_.Line,$_.Context.PreContext[0].Trim()}
```

But I've rarely extracted to Excel so I don't know How I could achieve the rest :/.

Comment: What decides how many lines before the matching line must be returned?

Comment: That's the thing, the number of lines before the match is unknown, that's why I want ALL the lines before it, I just put a "?" as a placeholder for now since I don't know the correct syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `switch` to handle the files line-by-line and use a (quite long) regex to parse out the data into objects.
Once you have gone though the log file and gathered the data as objects, you can use `Export-Csv` to write it all out in structured CSV files you can simply open in Excel.

```
$move  = "X:\New\test\Output"
$root  = "X:\New\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.log' -File

$Results = foreach($file in $files) {
    $data = switch -Regex -File $file.FullName {
        # exit the switch if we reach a line with 'Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER'
        'Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER' { break }
        # parse the string into named matches
        '^(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<idleft>[^\s]+)\s+(?<idright>\d+)\s+(?<error>\d+)\s+(?<details>(.+))$' {
            # output an object with the wanted properties
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'Client ID'  = '{0}-{1}' -f $matches['idleft'], $matches['idright']
                'Date'       = $matches['date']
                'Time'       = $matches['time']
                'Error code' = $matches['error']
                'Detail'     = $matches['details']
            }
        }
    }
    $target = Join-Path -Path $move -ChildPath $file.Name
    # export the gathered data to a csv you can double-click to open in Excel
    $data | Export-Csv -Path $target -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Using your example log, this would open in Excel as:

[image]

---

From your comment I understand you want to parse the data from all the files and save it in one large csv file in the same folder.
For that do:

```
$root  = "X:\New\test"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Filter '*.log' -File

$Results = foreach($file in $files) {
    switch -Regex -File $file.FullName {
        # exit the switch if we reach a line with 'Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER'
        'Command: MANUAL ROLLOVER' { break }
        # parse the string into named matches
        '^(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?<idleft>[^\s]+)\s+(?<idright>\d+)\s+(?<error>\d+)\s+(?<details>(.+))$' {
            # output an object with the wanted properties
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'Client ID'  = '{0}-{1}' -f $matches['idleft'], $matches['idright']
                'Date'       = $matches['date']
                'Time'       = $matches['time']
                'Error code' = $matches['error']
                'Detail'     = $matches['details']
            }
        }
    }
} 
$target = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath 'LogResults.csv'
# export the gathered data to a csv you can double-click to open in Excel
$Results | Export-Csv -Path $target -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

---

If you need for instance every Client ID to become its own csv file so you can load these as separate Excel sheets, you can do:

```
$Results | Group-Object 'Client ID' | ForEach-Object { 
    $target = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath ('{0}.csv' -f $_.Name)
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $target -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

I'm not too familiar with the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module, but I believe this may work:

```
$target = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath 'LogResults.xlsx'
$Results | Group-Object 'Client ID' | ForEach-Object { 
    $_.Group | Export-Excel -Path $target -Autosize -WorksheetName $_.Name
}
```

Comment: Ok this kinda works, but it seems to be producing one output for each file, I was expecting a single file with all the lines from all the files. And also there is a typo in my code, ignore the line with the $move variable, I just have a folder with the original files and I need the outputted CSV in the same folder

Comment: @Olbrok Please see my edit for that.

Comment: Yes, it works, tweaked it a little bit to directly output in an Excel workbook :).

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot but is there a way to apply filters on each headers then output the filtered result in a new tab ?

Comment: @Olbrok You mean like group on column `Client ID` and have each group become a separate csv file (in Excel a new sheet)? In that case please see my edit.

Comment: I tried to use your code and modify it to output the data in an Excel workbook. I find it easier to format column and apply autofilters in Excel. Thing is I can't find the correct way to adapt the code to do that. I can't install ImportExcel on thic computer without raising a ticket that will take saveral days to get a response ...

Comment: @Olbrok csv files are just structured data files. They do not have anything in them to manipulate how Excel treats that data. It might be possible in PowerShell and Excel COM objects, but I suggest you post a new question about that in which you make perfectly clear what filters should be used, as this no longer has anything to do with the original question.

Comment: Ok I just decided to export both data into separate csv files, I'm having another issue with leading zeros, I want to split the Client ID object into 2 different columns. Tried a simple 'column 1' = $matches['idleft']  but the CSV does not keep the leading zeroes. Tried to specify a format = '{0:d3}' -f $matches['idleft'] but still no leading zeroes, any idea ?

Comment: @Olbrok I see no zeroes in your examples for the Client ID..  The CSV should contain the leading zeroes. Just open in notepad to see that. I suspect you mean that **Excel** is converting to number and thus removes leading zeroes. If you want to have Excel respect these, prefix the value with a TAB character in the CSV. (something like ``"`t{0}" -f $matches['idleft']``

Comment: Great that works flawlessly ! And yes there are no leading zeroes in the example but some clients have leading zeroes in the files. Anyway thank you again :).